# Function for adding and deleting div based on checkboxes they are dependant on

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a JavaScript-based application which only needs to work in IE8 and 9.

This is a simplified description of the problem:

```
<div id="A" style="display:none">
<div id="a1">content of a1</div>
<div id="a2">content of a2</div>
<div id="a3">content of a3</div>
...goes on
</div>

<div id="B">
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
<div id="b3"></div>
...goes on
</div>`
```

I have a checkbox for each div under div "A".

I need a simple JavaScript function that will copy, or delete, the content of the divs under div "A" to those under div "B" depending on which of the checkboxes are checked.

For example, if checkbox "a1" is checked, the content of div "a1" will get copied to div "b1", or delete the content of "b1" if the box is unchecked.

Simple as that is, although I can't figure it out, the whole div "B" will be then copy-pasted to an email, so the div "B" cannot contain any hidden elements. I can not use textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified Markup and Javascript code. Please note the use of class attribute in the checkbox element to find out the source and destination divs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="A" style="display:none">
<div id="a1">content of a1</div>
<div id="a2">content of a2</div>
<div id="a3">content of a3</div>
</div>

<div id="B">
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
<div id="b3"></div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="3">
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
       var source= $("#a" + $(this).attr('class'));
       var destination= $("#b" + $(this).attr('class'));
       if($(this).attr('checked')=='checked')
          $(destination).html($(source).html());
       else     
           $(destination).html("");
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qmQM/1/

Comment: wow... that is exaclty what I meant. you are really good. now just one last question, if I may. It seems to work just fine in the jsfiddle.net tool, but it does not seem to work in the simple html document? do i need to call any library or anything?

Answer (score 1):

On the check-box events call this function:

```
function CopyInnerHtml(){
    var innerHTML = document.getElementById('A').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly that would not do, this function would override the full content of the Div "A" to Div "B" (and will not delete if unticked).

Comment: document.getElementById('B').oldInnerHtml = document.getElementById('B').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('B').innerHTML += innerHTML;


on uncheck

document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = document.getElementById('B').oldInnerHtml;